# How to fire migration where connection string is in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

In my application, there are multiple tenants and for each tenant we have created new database. So for new development, when we need to change some table structure we need to fire migration commands for each tenant db.

Is there any way to execute migration command on dynamic connection strings in one shot? Our connection string is in DB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to execute migrations on several databases in one shot.
You have to call the migration command for every single connection string in a loop.

You can either call it programatically with C# or create a Powershell script that runs migrate.exe.

We use the second option in our deployment, so that database migrations are an explicit step in the release pipeline.

Migrate.exe has a parameter to provide the connection string. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/migrate-exe#provide-connection-string) for more details.